# Why is the size of an uploaded file detected by the browser not the same as the size in the file system

Tags: jquery, browser, filesystems, size

I want to prevent users from uploading files bigger than 1 Go in the `<asp:FileUpload />`. The problem is that a file that show a size of 993 Mo (0.993 Go) in the file system is detected (using jQuery) with ...

```
 $(":file").change(function () {
        alert($(this)[0].files[0].size);
});
```

... as having a size of 1,017 Go in the web browser (both chrome and IE tell the same value). How is that and how can I have an accurate validation of the form if both size (browser one and file system one) are different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may or may not know already, there are two systems of measuring file size: binary and decimal. In binary, there are 1024 KB per 1 MB, 1024 MB per 1 GB, etc. In decimal, there are 1000 KB per 1 MB, 1000 MB per 1 GB, etc. There may be a difference in the way each program/company/whatever measures data.

Comment: Spot on, I feel dumb to have forgotten that

Comment: But since some time now we have kibi mibi and gibi for the binary system and kilo mega and giga for the decimal one

Comment: So actually MB = 1000 KB but MiB = 1024 KiB

Answer (score 0):

The size on the filesystem is the actual size required to store the file - it may be different from the byte length of file contents because filesystem is clustered.
File occupies clusters on disk and the area of the cluster which is not used to actually store data is wasted.
This causes the difference between real size of a file and the size on disk.

Comment: And I'm not sure if the [Gibibyte/Gigabyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) confusion doesn't play a role here too...

Comment: @Bartdude I feel dumb, I indeed forgot this, if I multiply the size in filesystem by 1024 I find the value detected by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

to add function u can get the size of file

```
    add: function (e, data) {
                try {

                    var imageKbytes = parseFloat(data.files[0].size / 1024);
                    var ImageMbytes = parseFloat(imageKbytes) / 1024;
                    if (ImageMbytes > parseFloat(2.0)) {
                        $("#errormessage").text("Please upload image upto 2 MB only");
                        return;
                    }
                 }
             catch (ex) {
                OpenAlertDialog(ex.message);
                  }
    }
```